# Formula for checking the probability of a character appearing multiple times consecutively in an encrypted string

Tags: cryptography, statistics, character, formula

My question today is fairly specific and not so much about programming, more about statistics.

I asked myself if there is a formula how often a character is likely to appear multiple times in a row. I made the assumption that every printable character on the keyboard (95) is equally likely to appear, so that the formula would be something like:

```
1/95^n(*95) (= 1/95^(n-1))
```

(*95 if you are not making any assumptions which character and are happy with just any)

I am sorry for the eye-hurting formatting, but I did not know how to format it more clearly

Now that is kind of nice as a formula, but it is based on too many assumptions and I am sure somebody has made more of that than an educated guess. Could you point me to a paper, a person or just the formula?

EDIT: This may be different for different encryption algorithms. Up until now, I have not dwelled in the realm of statistics in cryptography. If someone could provide a paper on that(specifically character appearance probability) that would be nice as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ideally, a cipher should produce ciphertext that is indistinguishable from random data. In fact, any cipher that does not fill this criterion is fundamentally weak.

In random data, each byte value is equally likely. An 8-bit byte can have 256 different values, so the probability of *n* consecutive bytes with the same value is (1/256)^(*n*-1).